# How to develop a good touch GUI?

Tags: android, user-interface

I've always developed application for personal use on command line. 
Now I have to develop an app for android for a broad audience.

If I start now I would make and awful GUI.  I need first to educate myself on the matter of building clear, efficient and usable GUI on a touch interface.

Any advice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could read the [**Android User Interface Guidelines**](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/index.html) and the [**iPhone Human Interface Guidelines**](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Answer (score 1):

First thing first, don't think about how to build a good GUI. Getting yourself to know what is a good GUI is far more important. Try using different application to see which one you feel good about it. Then read the guide in the answer above.